# StackTrace – Track your reputation and badges

Tags: app, reputation, badges, extension

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: Screenshot]

### About

This is a basic app that shows your reputation change.

#### Download

[Download the extension](http://twopointzero.us/code/StackTrace/StackTrace.safariextz)

#### Platform

This works on Safari 5.1 or later.

### Contact

Created by Jed Fox (contact me)

### Code

[Get the code](http://twopointzero.us/code/StackTrace/StackTrace.safariextension)

### Update Log:

#### Version 1.1 released:

- The profile icon now links to your profile.
- StackTrace is no longer restricted to [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/).

#### Version 1.0

*Initial version*